# Trying to provide a global logging function

Tags: python, logging

I typically write my scripts with a structure like s

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import stuff

def do_things():
    print "FOO"

def main():
    do_things()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem I have is I'd like to have a logging function that is defined globally and I"m not really sure how to do this. I tried a decorator function but if I define it in main I can't call it from other functions in the script. It seems like something that should be easy to do but not something I have experience with.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the logging module in the standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import logging
```

Python's [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) library should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I did look at the logging library but for some reason I thought I had to create a logging object and pass it around to my functions as I called them instead of using it as a global object. Thanks :)

Comment: As long as you `import logging` in each module where you need it, you will be able to access your `logger` from within the `logging` namespace.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond it did solve my needs perfectly!